# How to get geolocation, accelerometer readings in nodeJS?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, geolocation, accelerometer

I'd like to write NodeJS application which will be installed for local consumption only (i.e. operations on the hosted device, rather than e.g. web-serving).
I don't want to use an external service like google maps to get the geolocation; I actually want something similar to the HTML5 geolocation and accelerometer API, but I don't want to have to go through a browser.
Think running ubuntu / node headless, and streaming geolocation and acclerometer data to a logfile.

All searches so far don't provide a solution under these constraints.